# if I add an update in drill up events it causes the labels to disappear on the highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label

i add some update for scroll bar and if i drill up labels dissapear

[image]

and this is my first drilldown chart

[image]

and this after drilldown

[image]

and this after drillup

[image]

this a example jsfield 'https://jsfiddle.net/ariyan1919/o6hzbfgm/4/' can you correct what the uncorrect for my code thanks bro

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with sample data on some online editor?

Comment: hi @SebastianWędzel i make in js field https://jsfiddle.net/ariyan1919/o6hzbfgm/4/  i hope is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `setExtremes` feature triggered after drillup breaks the working of the dataLabels. But it seems that everything works as expected without this part of the code, do you need it? For what purpose?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7wueps4d/

Comment: thankyou bro Sebastian, its work from me but i have another way i use setExtremes but i add false in set max and min this is jsfiddle [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ariyan1919/8c4hpxqe/) gbu bro